# install4j - "Installation" ist not optimized for your Mac and needs to be updated

Tags: install4j

We have created a large installtion with install4j in our company (including  custom screen, launchers ...)
But in macOS Mojave we get the message: "Installation" ist not optimized for your Mac and needs to be updated.
"install4jc" is used to create the installer and jdk/jre is 64bit.
install4j-version is "7.0.7 b7204"
What is causing this message?

Comment: This is definitely a warning about 32-bit libraries. Do you maybe ship any native libraries that are 32-bit?

Comment: macOS identifies the file "install4j" in the sub-directory ".install4j" of our application as a 32-bit application. The parent process is identified to "/Applications/OurApp/Deinstallationsprogramm.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub"

Answer (score 1):

Since install4j 7.0.8, this executable also includes the "x86_64" architecture, so this warning will not appear anymore.

Comment: This is the information, I've searched for. Should be added in the changelog at https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/install4j/changelog.html